# (Android) Cookie problems in HttpClient, URL and HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, php, android, cookies, captcha

I am going to add a captcha validation in the registration form in android apps. But I found that server gives signal to me that there is no session. Finally, I found that the cookie of my application stored nothing.

[image]

I cannot register account even though the validation is correct. I am sure that there is no problem in my php server because I have tested that in browser.

I have made three types of connection to test the cookie issue.

1) HttpClient

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

2) URL

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://www.example.com/abc.png").getContent());
```

3) HttpURLConnection

```
private void send_post(HttpURLConnection connection,String variable_set) throws Exception
{
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(variable_set.getBytes().length));
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(variable_set);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
}
```

Also, I add this code to setup cookie.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();  
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Unfortunately, only HttpURLConnection successes to use cookie and server shows there are some session variables. Yet, my application is mainly using URL and HttpClient.

Could anyone tell me how to enable cookie in HttpClient and URL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to set JSESSIONID (of Apache Tomcat server) as a cookie in Android. Hope this will give you some idea for doing similar process in PHP:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.setCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore());
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID<<or your variable name>>", <<ACTUAL VALUE>>);
cookie.setDomain(<<SET YOUR DOMAIN NAME HERE>>);
cookie.setPath("/");
httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookie);
HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
// Checking http request method type
if (method == POST) {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); //use text/plain if response if HTTP response is plain text
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                
    if (formData != null) {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formData, HTTP.UTF_8));
    }
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
} else if (method == GET) {
    if (formData != null) {
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(formData, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;
    }
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
}

status_code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
Log.i("Status Code After Login", "> >status code > >" + status_code + "> >url > >"+url);
if(status_code==200)
    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
else
    response="fail";

<<response will contain the final HTTP response>>
```